# Divergence Theorem question2

Tags: calculus, vectors

I need to use the divergence theorem to evaluate $$\iint_S F \cdot n dS$$ when $F=y^2xi + x^2yj + z^2k$ and when S is the complete surface of the region bounded by the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and by the planes $z=0$ $z=2$

So I know the divergence theorem states:

$$\iint_S F \cdot n dS$$ = $$\iiint_S divF \cdot dV$$

So my solution:

$$\iiint_{0}^{2} (y^2 + 2xy) dz dx dy$$=$$\iint zy^2 + 2zy|0 to 2 dx dy$$
=$$\iint 2y^2 +4xy dx dy$$

From here I'm not sure how to get the bound for x and y, once I can get those I can finish the problem.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: switch to cylindrical polar coordinates! (clue's in the question!)

Comment: Isn't $\nabla\cdot F=y^2+x^2+2z$?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int\int\int_V\mathrm{div}\vec{F}\cdot dV&=\int_\mathcal{C}\int_0^2\left(x^2+y^2+2z\right)dxdydz\\
&=\int_\mathcal{C}\int_0^2\left(4+2z\right)dxdydz\\
&=\int_\mathcal{C}\left[4z+z^2\right]_0^2dS\\
&=\int_\mathcal{C}12\ dS\\
&=\pi\cdot 2^2\cdot 12\\
&=48\pi
\end{align}

where $\mathcal{C}$ is the circle centred at the origin and of radius $r=2$, defined by the constraint equation $x^2+y^2=4$.

Comment: how does $(x^2+y^2+2z)$ turn into $(4+2z)$?

Comment: Using the equation of the circle $x^2+y^2=4$. This is essentially a shortcut to transform everything in cylindrical coordinates. You would normally keep $z$ as it is (the height of the cylinder), and have $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, with what I called $\int_\mathcal{C}dS$ (the surface integral over the circle) being actually $\int_{0}^{2}rdr\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta$. Instead, we use the known equation of the circle, with surface area $=\pi r^2$.